# How to override Parsley.js default config to use across a project

Tags: jquery, validation, config, parsley.js

I'm trying to change the default settings of Parsley so it matches the style formatting of Bootstrap 3.x.

I found this code snippet: https://gist.github.com/askehansen/6809825

I added this after the "Parsley.min.js" (using v2.0.0 by the way) file, but it seems not to be working at all. I use the DOM api only, not the regular js parsley() call.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, this gist is not anymore valid with 2.x versions. The default config is here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html

You could update above gist to make it works with new option config object, mainly, it would look to something similar to that:

```
  window.ParsleyConfig = {
    classHandler: function ( elem, isRadioOrCheckbox ) {
      // specify where parsley error-success classes are set
      return $(elem).parents(".form-group");
    },
    errorsWrapper: '<span class="help-block"></span>',
    errorTemplate: '<span></span>' 
   };
```

Secondly, you need to define `window.ParsleyConfig` **before** calling parsley.min.js

Please have a look to the documentation to understand how ParsleyConfig works and how you could use it to customize your whole Parsley behavior: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-global-configuration

Comment: Yes did the trick! And thank you so much for developing this awesome plugin.

Only thing I had to change was:

`return parsleyField.$element.parents('.form-group');`

Comment: How would one add their own custom error messages to the config in this manner?  I can't seem to figure it out.